# Auto layout iOS não funciona corretamente Xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layout

Estou desenvolvendo um App em Xcode 8.x.

Estou com um problema em redimensionar 4 botões na primeira tela.
Trabalho no design do iPhone 5 ou 6 e configuro todo o auto layout, quando rodo em todos os devices está legal menos no Iphone 4 onde posso abrir no Ipad, mas os botoes no redimensionam apenas sobe, queria uma sugestão no onde eu estaria errando, estou usando o auto layout da seguinte forma, clico com o direito e arrasto para o lado e uso o horizontal space etc. e sucessivamente.

veja as imagens:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Alguma chance de você estar usando altura fixa para os botões e a tela não ter altura suficiente para exibir todos eles um acima do outro na altura definida?

Comment: Então eu fiz sempre da mesma maneira para UIView, estou achando q seja isso mesmo, vou rever esse conceito.

Comment: Se o problema for esse, voce pode colocar os botões em uma stackview. Aí ela se encarrega de fazer a distribuição dos botões de forma que eles caibam na tela

Comment: a melhor forma que achei foi, verificar o device, e posicionei e redimensionei eles em seus lugar, foi o mais rapido deu certinho.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, uma alternativa para você poder apresentar o último botão no iPhone 4 é usar uma **TableView** com *células estáticas* :)

E caso sua lista de itens aumente, você não vai mais ter este problema este modelo de iPhone.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, acho que será uma alternativa.vou ver se consigo fazer dessa forma. valeu.

Comment: Se não me engano pra usar células estáticas, você obrigatoriamente precisa ter um TableViewController (não pode ser um ViewController com uma TableView dentro). Não sei se é viável no seu projeto

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, 
fica difícil dar qualquer sugestão a partir de Autolayout... onde há diversas formas de você chegar em um resultado.

Uma alternativa seria você tentar configurar o layout a partir do iPhone 4s, e deixar o iOS e as constraints adaptarem para os demais devices.

Da seguinte forma:
[image: view as iphone 4s]

uma vez o seu layout "encaixado" no tamanho do iphone 4s, o restante irá funcionar.

Quanto ao tamanho dos botões, tente utilizar altura baseado no tamanho da tela... é um trabalho meio "chato" mas é uma solução bem boa. Já usei diversas vezes. Basta fazer para um botão, e dar um "equal height" para os demais.

Tipo isso:

1 - Iguala altura da view em questão igual a altura da superview
[image: altura da view igual a da superview]

2 - Vai na constraint que voce acabou de criar, e clica em editar:
[image: editar constraint de altura]

3 - No atributo multiplier, você seleciona o multiplicador dessa constraint. O valor funciona como porcentagem. Sendo 0: zero porcento; e 1: 100%. No meu exemplo coloquei 12% do tamanho da tela, ou seja 0.12.
[image: editar atributo multiplicador]

Após isso, você poderia deixar os demais botão com a altura igual ao do botão que você acabou de alterar.

Enfim... é isso. Espero que ajude.

JLU.